# Date as a user input using my own Date class

Tags: java, date, oop, java.util.scanner

I'm developing an application, and in there I have to take the date from the user, and it's only date, time is not required. And I was asked to use a `Date` class to represent the date. But I don't have any idea on how to get the date from the user as a normal input using scanner class.

The date class is shown below, so how can I get the input as a date?

I'm new to programming so please help me to solve this issue.

```
public class Date {

    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;

    public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Date{" +
                "day=" + day +
                ", month=" + month +
                ", year=" + year +
                '}';
    }
}
```

This is an assignment, and it asks us to implement a `Date` class like this, and it asks us to avoid using any predefined libraries in Java.

Comment: Please add some more background information to your question: Why do you need this custom `Date` class at all? There is already `java.time.LocalDate`, which is included since Java 8 and is well-tested.

Comment: You just need look at this example: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/java-8-convert-string-localdate-example/#:~:text=ofPattern%20method%20returns%20the%20DateTimeFormatter,object%20to%20do%20other%20operations

Comment: Guys, I was asked to implement a Date class and not to use any predefined libraries in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that this is homework and that you are not allowed to use `LocalDate` from the standard library (as one would unconditionally do in production code).

Options include (and are not limited to):

1. Read day of month, month and year as three numbers in turn using three calls to `Scanner.nextInt()`. Pass the three numbers to your `Date` constructor.
2. Read the date as for example `29-05-2020` from the user using either `Scanner.next()` or `Scanner.nextLine()`. Split at hyphens. Parse each number to an `int` using `Integer.parseInt()`. Pass the three parsed numbers to the constructor.

Doc links:

- [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))
- [`Integer.parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 2):

## `java.time.LocalDate`

We have a class for that: [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html). Do not reinvent the wheel.

And be aware that date-time handling is surprisingly tricky work — do not attempt roll-your-own solutions. Always use the industry-leading *java.time* classes.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2021 , 1 , 23 ) ;  // January 23, 2021.
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

> 2021-01-23

In a console app, using the `Scanner` class, ask the user to input a date in ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM-DD.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2021-01-23" ) ;
```

Or, ask for the year, month, and day inputs separately. [Parse each as an integer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)), and pass the three `int` values to `LocalDate.of` as seen above.

Tips:

- Organize your thinking and code to work with greater scope first, and detailed scope later. So year-month-day rather than day-month-year.
- Learn about [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for formatting date-time values as text when exchanging data.
- Study the *java.time* [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: this assignment asks us to implement a Date class like this and it asks us to avoid using any predefined libraries in java.

Comment: @archWarrior You should identify your Question as a school assignment when first posting. Your first sentence suggests the opposite.